# How Can I Put While Loop SQL Results in A Table in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to put the results of an SQL query inside of a table and everytime theres a new result to make a new table data box. My code looks like

```
<html>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
</style>
<?php
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
     <th>
          message
     </th>
</tr> 
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";   
}
?>
```

But it makes a new box horizontally. How can I make it vertical and how can I also make it so it works for more than just one `th` element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `<tr>`'s (which indicates new rows in your table)

```
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['message'] . '</td>';   
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

If you want to use more `<th>`'s, then you need to add more `<td>`'s.

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
     <th>
          message
     </th>
     <th>
         foo
     </th>
</tr> 
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['message'] . '</td>';   
    echo '<td>' . $row['foo'] . '</td>';   
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

`<th>` and `<td>` are for setting columns and `<tr>` are for setting rows. So just make sure you have the same number of `<th>`'s and `<td>`'s.

I would recommend that you read up on how HTML [tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) work.

Answer (score 0):

wrapp a `<tr>` short for table row around your `<td>` table data.

```
while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['message'] . "</td></tr>";   
}
```

Don't forget to end the table  after the loop if thats what you want to do.